# "Error: Module name 'underscore' has not been loaded yet for context: _" happens sometimes on Firefox only

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

This code is working fine on Chrome, IE and also android and IOS but an issue occurs sometimes on Firefox. After a few reload of the page the issue is gone!

```
Error: Module name 'underscore' has not been loaded yet for context: _
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded require.js (line 7, col 217)
```

The code :

core.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        text: 'libs/text',
        loader: 'libs/backbone/loader',
        jQuery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
        Underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore',
        Backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone',
        'hammer': 'libs/jquery/hammer-min'
    },

    shim: {
        Underscore: { deps: ['jQuery'] },
        Backbone: { deps: ['Underscore'] }
    }
});

require(['routers/core'], function (App) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        App.start();
    });
});
```

routers/core.js

```
define([
    'jQuery',
    'Underscore',
    'Backbone',

    'routers/common'

], function ($, _, Backbone, CommonRouter) {

    var start = function () {
        var app = {
            init: function () {

            }
        };
        _.extend(CommonRouter.prototype, app);

        var app_router = new CommonRouter;
        Backbone.history.start();
    };

    return { start: start };

});
```

libs/backbone/loader.js

```
define([
    'libs/jquery/jquery-base64',
    'libs/jquery/jquery-easing',
    'libs/jquery/jquery-inputmask',
    'libs/jquery/jquery-mousewheel',
    'libs/jquery/jquery-tagsinput',
    'libs/jquery/jquery-validate',
    'libs/jquery/highcharts',
    'libs/jquery/raphael',
    'libs/jquery/selectreplace',
    'libs/jquery/touchswipe',
    'libs/jquery/flowplayer-min',

    'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
    'libs/backbone/backbone-min'
],
function(){
  return {
    Backbone: Backbone.noConflict(),
    _: _.noConflict(),
    $: jQuery.noConflict()
  };
});
```

The issue is that Backbone: Backbone.noConflict(), is `undefined` because the module "underscore" is not loaded yet.

How can I wait and be sure the modules required are loaded when I need them?

Comment: Where & how are you loding `libs/backbone/loader.js`..? Why are you not using the path used in `shim` for backbone in it..? Side note: `Underscore: { deps: ['jQuery'] }` this is wrong. underscore has no dependency on jquery

Comment: any news on this? I'm having the same prob

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> How can I wait and be sure the modules required are loaded when I need them?

We can use the `shim` option of configuration for that.

To setup `jQuery` and `underscore` as dependencies of `backbone` you should do:

```
shim: {
    backbone: { deps: ['jQuery','underscore'] }
}
```

---

You seem to have setup jQuery as a dependency of underscore where there is no actual dependency between them, which is unnecessary.

Apart from that you seems to have few issues -

First of all, you haven't specified any arguments to your `libs/backbone/loader.js` module. Since there is no global `backbone` or `_` in window, unless you specify these your module won't have a way to access to the exports apart from the `arguments` object, unless somehow it's available in it's the parent scope.

Most of your imports seems to be jQuery plugins that just modifies jQuery. In such case you should specify them after all other libs that actually exports something which you want to use so that you don't have to specify an argument for each.

another issue could be that you're using the short path names to setup the `shim` option but you're using the full path (for eg `libs/backbone/backbone-min`) to load the libraries in `libs/backbone/loader.js`.

I wonder how it works for you in other browsers without specifying the import names as arguments.

```
 define([
     'underscore',
     'jquery',
     'backbone'
     'libs/jquery/jquery-base64',
     'libs/jquery/jquery-easing',
     'libs/jquery/jquery-inputmask',
     'libs/jquery/jquery-mousewheel',
     'libs/jquery/jquery-tagsinput',
     'libs/jquery/jquery-validate',
     'libs/jquery/highcharts',
     'libs/jquery/raphael',
     'libs/jquery/selectreplace',
     'libs/jquery/touchswipe',
     'libs/jquery/flowplayer-min'
   ],
   function(_,
     $,
     Backbone
     /*all other imports in order*/
   ) {
     return {
       Backbone: Backbone.noConflict(),
       _: _.noConflict(),
       $: jQuery.noConflict()
     };
   });
```

<sub>*side note: I modified the first letter of path names to small letter because I prefer having a consistent naming convention*</sub>